# Comparing previous row values in Pandas DataFrame in different column

Tags: python, pandas

my input:

```
first=pd.Series([0,1680,5000,14999,17000])
last =pd.Series([4999,7501,10000,16777,21387])
dd=pd.concat([first, last], axis=1)
```

I trying find&compare second value in first column (e.g. `1680`) and "range" previous row between first value in first column to first value in second column(e.g. from `0` to `4999`). So in my condition value `1680` fall in range previous row between `0` to `4999`, also 3td value in first column `5000` fall in range previous row between `1680` to `7501`, but other values (e.g. `14999`, `17000`) not in range of previous rows.
My expect output something like this:
`[1680]`, `[5000]` so show only values that fall in my condition
I trying with `diff()`: `dd[0].diff().gt(dd[1])` or `reshape`/`shift` but not really success

Comment: Can you please put the expected dataframe?

Comment: I am not really necessary output as df, only value that fall in my condition, but if solution as df it will be great too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shift` and `between` to compare a row with the previous one:

```
>>> df[0].loc[df[0].between(df[0].shift(), df[1].shift())]
1    1680
2    5000
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Details of `shift`:

```
>>> pd.concat([df[0], df.shift()], axis=1)
       0        0        1
0      0      NaN      NaN
1   1680      0.0   4999.0
2   5000   1680.0   7501.0
3  14999   5000.0  10000.0
4  17000  14999.0  16777.0
```